# How to stop "Floppy Disk" icon from appearing in 13.04 launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, floppy

Whenever I remove external hard drive or USB flash drive, a Floppy Disk icon appears in launcher. If I unlock it, it goes away but only until I use a USB device again.

How to stop this?

BTW I don't have an actual floppy disk drive installed. However, in Nautilus "Floppy Disk" is listed among devices. Is this normal?

Answer (score 4):

You can try creating an udev rule to hide the floppy from the unity launcher and nautilus.

### For Ubuntu 12.10 & 13.04

1. Create the udev rule.

   - `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-floppy.rules`

     Match the *KERNEL* key with your device *(floppy=fd*)* and assign the *UDISKS* 
     variable.
   - The content of the `99-hide-floppy.rules` file would be:

     ```
     KERNEL=="fd*", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
     ```
   - To save the changes in nano... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and finally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
2. Finally refresh the udev rules with:

   - `sudo udevadm trigger`

---

### For Ubuntu 12.04

- The only difference is the name of the UDISKS variable.
  It should be *`ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}`* instead *`ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}`*

  ```
  KERNEL=="fd*", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
  ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into your bios settings and tell it you do not have a floppy drive.